# Getting inline CSS generated by Elementor with the Wordpress Rest API

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, elementor

I am using the Wordpress REST API to retrieve the rendered content of a wordpress page. 
My page is constructed with Elementor. And Elementor is adding some inline CSS on the finale page to make all work. This inline CSS is not present in 
the content returned by the API.

Example call:

`http://website.com/guide/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/23412`

Response:

`<h1>My title</h1>`

Real page HTML:

`<h1>My title</h1>  <style>h1 { color: red; }</style>`

Part am I looking for (not present in the response):

`<style>h1 { color: red; }</style>`

Do you know how I can retrieve the inline CSS generated by Elementor with the Wordpress API ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution described here works pretty well :
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292849/displaying-a-page-built-with-elementor-using-the-rest-api/292895

Once the HTML recieved you can parse the page and get the `<style>` tag with all the Elementor generated inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple way to get the content of an Elementor into a variable along with styles, I used this to display a single page on all subdomains of a multisite.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307783/echoing-elementor-page-content-in-template-but-it-doesnt-get-styles-and-some-w

I’ll add on my own that this code worked for me (with the second argument true)

```
$pluginElementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
$contentElementor = $pluginElementor->frontend->get_builder_content($post_ID, $with_css = true);
```